# Constraint issues ios- Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I am working an ios app using Xcode 7.0.1 and swift 2.0. I want to design app for all ios devices iphone's and ipad's. I am using wAny, hAny in storyboard. I use constraints also. One of my screen i have some buttons and i want to change height of buttons. I add my storyboard screenshot [image].

Now my problem here is i want all the buttons same width and height at initial stage after that i need to change height. So i use equal height constraints. Initially it is working. How can i change height of one Button using swift code.

**Note**: I am using view to place the buttons because it have label inside so.

Comment: you would like to change the height of the buttons programmatically?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the hight.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect constraint of the button (which will provide height to all other buttons) as IBOutlet.

And if you connected try this

```
baseButtonHeightConstraint.constant = 70.0 //for example
```

Comment: If i set Height constraint i can do this. But i am using equal height for all the buttons. I tried like your answer. But it showing conflicting contraints error.

Comment: When it is not conflicting, do you have any constraint which defines height of button?

Comment: No i am not using any height constraint. I am using equalHeight contraints only.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the button that you want to change the height, In the size inspector which is on the right top, change the height and save it. Try running then.